# Is there a design pattern that would prevent a classes method from running until one or more requirements are made?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, methods, roles

Is there a design pattern that would prevent a classes method from running until one or more requirements are made?

An example could be a Car and getting it going, to start the car it will need petrol, keys in the ignition, and then turning the key.

How would one solve the problem of dependant requirements (and the necessary ordering), the ignition won't start without a key in, and a key wont turn if its not inserted.

Here are two methods I know which both have pitfalls:-

```
void startCar()
    if checkPetrol()
        if checkKeyIn()
           if checkKeyTurn()
              startEngine()
```

Also using a switch statement is possible but then it requires a lot of checks as well.

How can one solve this?

Comment: You should look at the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: State pattern is not suitable here. You don't need a petrol to turn keys. All criteria should be met, so Composite predicate would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are a lot of other more suitable solutions, but [Observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern) can be used here. In fact it will allow you to define a dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically. I'm thinking of something like combine it with [Facade design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern) (only `startCar()` is *public*)with proper Exception handling:

```
void startCar(){
    if (checkPetrol()){
        if (checkKeyIn()){
           if (checkKeyTurn()){
              startEngine()
           }else{
            throw new CarCustomException("You need to turn the key in order to start.");
           }  
        }else{
         throw new CarCustomException("Car can't start without a key.");
        }
   }else{
      throw new CarCustomException("Not enough fuel.");
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it is more readable this way, the flow of conditions is easy to understand and maintain